# Angular 2 - navigation of aux outlet affecting primary outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

- Functional requirements ( because the technical issue didn't make sense to the audience):

An angular 2 app must configure itself at startup. if no query parameters     are present ( e.g. default state ) it must show a default home and a default form.
If query parameters are present instead, a customization process takes place. The customization process basically shows a customized home and form.

- Technical requirements:

The plunker is an over-simplified version of actual functional requirements ( query parameters parsing omitted ) which basically switches the head component.
The call should take place in the main component since the parsing logic ( not included in the plunker) lies there.

```
this.route.queryParams.filter(qp => !_.isEmpty(qp)).subscribe(qp => this.parseParameters(qp));
```

The **router.navigate** fails to perform the navigation in the named outlet ( header ) from AppComponent.
The same code works if used inside a subcomponent ( e.g. DefaultComponent)

Here's the plunkr ( please look at the commented code)

**DEMO : http://embed.plnkr.co/qyquCE4h5OX8sNLKM8lu/**

Adding some tracing I found out the router cancelled the navigation:

- Router Event: NavigationStart

  - NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/(header:head)')
- Router Event: NavigationStart

  - NavigationStart(id: 2, url: '/')
- Router Event: NavigationCancel

  - NavigationCancel {id: 1, url: "/(header:head)", reason: "Navigation ID 1 is not equal to the current navigation id 2"}

Question:

Are outlet trees mutually exclusive? In other words can I navigate the header outlet like this:

```
this.router.navigate(
[{
  outlets: {
    header: "head"
  }
}]
```

);

without affecting the primary outlet?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got what you want. When you run your app, you want *headComponent* in *named outlet* and *default component* in *regular outlet*. 

right????

To do that you need to change your routes to following,

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/lG66FIII9b9Xbi7YiHqc?p=preview**

**1)**

```
const headerRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DefaultComponent},
  { path: '', component: HeadComponent, outlet: headerOutlet}
];
```

**NOTE**: Now, you don't require below code,

```
ngOnInit() {

  /* now not required */  

  this.router.navigate(
    [{
      outlets: {
        header: "head"
      }
    }]
  );

}
```

**2)** This also solves your second(2) problem mentioned in your question.

Comment: I need a default header component in named outlet. 
At a later stage I need to update the header programmatically. 
I updated my plunker to show the issue ( AppComponent.ngOnInit)

Comment: I don't understand your requirement sorry. Once app runs, there is nothing to do in later stage so How and what to do in later stage? Requirement is not clear.

Comment: first of all, thanks for answering. Second, I edited the answer to include the requirements